# .NET - properly deploy and publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to deploy my .NET core web app + React application (generated by the `Visual Studio 2017`) to an Ubuntu server.
What I did

- cloned the repo with the project into `~/projects/doggy`
- executed `dotnet restore`
- installed and configured Nginx reverse proxy
- execute `dotnet run` and I can see my site live

but, I don't want to have the source code and the binaries in the same folder so I did

- created another folder `~/sites/doggy`
- within the folder `~/projects/doggy` I executed `dotnet publish -c Release -o ~/sites/doggy/`
- went to folder `~/sites/doggy` and executed `dotnet doggy.dll`

and here is a big kaboom.
I got this error

`Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (squeegeez.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.3'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.8.xml`

why the `publish` command can't copy all of the needed assemblies? How to properly do this?

I could not find a proper tutorial where the source code is independent to the place where it is deployed? Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally this should work, you did the steps needed. Can you check the `~/sites/doggy` folder see if the other packages got copied?

Comment: https://hjerpbakk.com/blog/2018/03/10/assembly-not-found